# Contact synchronization on older droids

Tags: contacts, insufficient-memory, import

Having had the "activate auto-sync" checkmark off for about a week (not that i expected this time-out to matter in any case), i've recently tried to find a manually-driven option, but without success. My 2.3.4 Gingerbread (Level 10) doesn't even animate the curved arrows anymore. After giving up, i've even activated the auto-sync, but it still did not kick in. :-|

Then i tried to look into other options, and got to the Contacts app, where in the Menu there's an "Import" option, but this one fails to even start -- with a silly error message "Memory full. Could not import contacts." My internal storage still has 16 MB free, though, so i suspect it's the number of contacts that's causing the issue? So, anyway, how do i check what's wrong and is there any workaround for this SNAFU?

Comment: To answer a part of your issue: Have you checked our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)? That error is triggered when your internal memory drops below ~25 MB, and could even affect the storage of an incoming (160-char) SMS, stupid as it might sound... Btw: first-aid is also available in the tag-wiki.

Comment: @Izzy : no, i didn't yet try any of those ideas since i haven't started considering the low internal space a problem... It's just a possible minor inconvenience when i want to install a new app. But do you really expect me to understand that "FULL" can actually mean "low space"?!?

Comment: @Izzy : on the other hand, i'm currently going through the effort of cataloguing (and backing up apks of) internal-storage-hungry apps, so maybe i should just be patient and try again after i finish that and decide which of them to uninstall?

Comment: As I wrote above, and the linked tag-wiki states: that error will always pop-up on low storage. So that is your underlying problem. The tag-wiki contains hints on how to deal with that; please check those out first. Afterwards, feel free to return with specific questions, of course, if there are any left :)